# how to select some values on the same column then remaining values as the new column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this code

```
insert into tblPernikahan values(1,"YUNIKA TRIRATNADI A","W","1981-11-29 23:11:10","YOGYAKARTA","2008-09-11 12:09:41"),
  (2,"YULIA","W","1976-12-05 19:12:21","SEMARANG","2011-10-23 05:10:45"),
  (3,"YOLA AZERTI SARI","W","1983-06-01 03:06:40","MAGELANG","2011-06-08 17:06:28"),
  (4,"YETI SULIANA","W","1986-04-18 04:04:50","YOGYAKARTA","2005-01-14 21:01:04"),
  (5,"YETI KURNIATI P","W","1976-02-18 21:02:18","MUNTILAN","2008-11-19 23:11:50"),
  (6,"ZIAD","P","1981-07-08 17:07:06","YOGYAKARTA","2008-09-11 12:09:41"),
  (7,"TUNJUNG ARIWIBOWO","P","1978-10-25 07:10:39","YOGYAKARTA","2011-10-23 05:10:45"),
  (8,"SUGIMAN","P","1976-09-28 01:09:38","MUNTILAN","2011-06-08 17:06:28"),
  (9,"SIGIT SUTOPO","P","1976-06-22 00:06:50","YOGYAKARTA","2005-01-14 21:01:04"),
  (10,"RICKY PERMANADJAYA","P","1989-06-09 07:06:23","MAGELANG","2008-11-19 23:11:50");
```

[image: weddingstable]
i want to spilt the 5 values on the nama column where the gender(jkelamin) is w into the new column as female
then the remaining values where the gender is P into the new column as Male

for the example

[image: female column] this as female column

[image: male column] this as male column

its like

YUNIKA TRIATNADI A is married to ZIAD

YULIA married to TUNJUNG ARIWIBOWO and so on.

how can i do this?

Comment: yeah only on the query @Strawberry

Comment: @Strawberry yeah its like couple table

Comment: @Strawberry yeah its male column and female column side by side

Comment: And if two people share the same marriage date, then it's assumed that they're married to each other.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every W has a P?

Comment: yeah assume they're married to each others @Strawberry

Comment: @P.Salmon every W has a P? W means female and P means male

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite get it - is "tglnikah" the date of marriage and the only way to identify who is married to each other? There may be multiple couples with identical marriage dates...
Otherwise you could do something like

```
SELECT t1.nama, t2.nama, t1.tglnikah FROM tblPernikahan t1, tblPernikahan t2 WHERE t1.jkelamin='W' AND t2.jkelamin='P' AND t1.tglnikah=t2.tglnikah AND t1.nama!=t2.nama;
```

Comment: Presumably this data relates to a single registry office, which is only capable of registering one marriage at a time.

Comment: damn i  actually just got the reasons why the marriage date between the male and the female is actually same, you are right dude

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table if exists weddings;

CREATE TABLE weddings
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
,gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
,dob DATETIME NOT NULL 
,birthplace VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,wedding_date DATE NOT NULL
);

insert into weddings values
(1,"YUNIKA TRIRATNADI A","W","1981-11-29 23:11:10","YOGYAKARTA","2008-09-11 12:09:41"),
  (2,"YULIA","W","1976-12-05 19:12:21","SEMARANG","2011-10-23 05:10:45"),
  (3,"YOLA AZERTI SARI","W","1983-06-01 03:06:40","MAGELANG","2011-06-08 17:06:28"),
  (4,"YETI SULIANA","W","1986-04-18 04:04:50","YOGYAKARTA","2005-01-14 21:01:04"),
  (5,"YETI KURNIATI P","W","1976-02-18 21:02:18","MUNTILAN","2008-11-19 23:11:50"),
  (6,"ZIAD","P","1981-07-08 17:07:06","YOGYAKARTA","2008-09-11 12:09:41"),
  (7,"TUNJUNG ARIWIBOWO","P","1978-10-25 07:10:39","YOGYAKARTA","2011-10-23 05:10:45"),
  (8,"SUGIMAN","P","1976-09-28 01:09:38","MUNTILAN","2011-06-08 17:06:28"),
  (9,"SIGIT SUTOPO","P","1976-06-22 00:06:50","YOGYAKARTA","2005-01-14 21:01:04"),
  (10,"RICKY PERMANADJAYA","P","1989-06-09 07:06:23","MAGELANG","2008-11-19 23:11:50");


SELECT w.name w
     , p.name p 
  FROM weddings w 
  JOIN weddings p 
    ON p.wedding_date = w.wedding_date 
   AND p.gender = 'p' 
 WHERE w.gender = 'w';
+---------------------+--------------------+
| w                   | p                  |
+---------------------+--------------------+
| YUNIKA TRIRATNADI A | ZIAD               |
| YULIA               | TUNJUNG ARIWIBOWO  |
| YOLA AZERTI SARI    | SUGIMAN            |
| YETI SULIANA        | SIGIT SUTOPO       |
| YETI KURNIATI P     | RICKY PERMANADJAYA |
+---------------------+--------------------+
```